# Javascript change of color with checkbox

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript here which is able to change color when checkbox is checked, but it had to rely on use of external libraries for it to work. Would it be possible for it not use external libraries such as function () ?

```
<p style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">I have read and agree to the terms and conditions
            <input type="checkbox" id="termsChkbx" onchange="isChecked(this,'sub1')"/></p>
```

JS:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#termsChkbx').change(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            $(this).parent('p').css('color','black');
        }
        else
        {
             $(this).parent('p').css('color','red');
        }
    });
```

Comment: *"Would it be possible for it to function () ?"* I don't understand this. Are you asking how to do it without external libraries? Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Sorry, yes i'm just asking if it can be done without external libraries.

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
function isChecked(elem) {
    elem.parentNode.style.color = (elem.checked) ? 'black' : 'red';
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/xc22j7u5/)**

Comment: May I ask where did elem come from ?

Comment: You passed it via `this` in `isChecked(this`. It refers to the checkbox being clicked on.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done without needing libraries. A fairly direct translation would be this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.getElementById('termsChkbx').addEventListener("change", function(){
        if(this.checked) {
           this.parentNode.style.color = "black";
        } else {
           this.parentNode.style.color = "red";
        }
    }, false);
});
```

Or a little shorter like this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.getElementById('termsChkbx').addEventListener("change", function(){
      this.parentNode.style.color = this.checked ? "black" : "red";
    }, false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="termsChkbx" onchange="termsChecked()"/>
```

And write a simple JS function:

```
function termsChecked() {
    var chk = document.getElementById('termsChkbx');
    if (chk.checked) {
         chk.parentNode.style.color = 'black';
    } else {
         chk.parentNode.style.color = 'red';
    }
}
```

This does put JS code in the HTML markup, which is not really preferable, but this will work with older browsers not supporting the `DOMContentLoaded` event. If you are targeting only modern browser, an *ActionListener* is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

try,

```js
function isChecked(){

  var chk = document.getElementById("termsChkbx");
  if(chk.checked){
     chk.parentElement.style.color  = "black";
  }
  else{
     chk.parentElement.style.color  = "red";
  }
}
```

```html
<p style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">I have read and agree to the terms and conditions
            <input type="checkbox" id="termsChkbx" onchange="isChecked()"/></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure javascript:

```
document.getElementById('termsChkbx').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('termsChkbx').parentElement.style.color = this.checked ? "black" : "red";
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#termsChkbx').on('change', function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
            if($(this).is(':checked'))
            {
                $(this).parent().css('color','black');
            }
            else
            {
                 $(this).parent().css('color','red');
            }
        });  
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <p style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">I have read and agree to the terms and conditions
    <input type="checkbox" id="termsChkbx" /></p>
</div>
```

Comment: The poster doesn't want to use external libraries

Comment: @jtsnr you are smarter than me, but when I answer OP doesn't said that. You are read that from a comment that not exists when I answer. Thank you for the downvote, if not yours, for the troll that downvote.